# Java regex , jsoup

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

How to extract these messages by regex or jsoup ? **19040172b-1**、 **SQL Server Develop** 、**zheng** 、**3-5,7-14** 、**D-101** ，

```html
<div id="AE9D7F630640426F8457A661607D2B8E-5-2" style="display: none;" class="kbcontent">
  19040172b-1
  <br>SQL Server Develop
  <br>
  <font title="teacher">zheng</font>
  <br>
  <font title="week">3-5,7-14</font>
  <br>
  <font title="classroom">D-101</font>
  <br>
 </div>
```

I have tried the following ways but failed.

```
1. Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(">(.*?)<br>");

2. Elements msg = doc.select(":matchesOwn([>.*?<br>])");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String html = "<div id=\"AE9D7F630640426F8457A661607D2B8E-5-2\" style=\"display: none;\" class=\"kbcontent\">  19040172b-1  <br>SQL Server Develop  <br>  <font title=\"teacher\">zheng</font>  <br>  <font title=\"week\">3-5,7-14</font>  <br>  <font title=\"classroom\">D-101</font>  <br> </div> ";
html = html.replaceAll("<br>", "#~#");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html.toString());
String newHtml = doc.text();
String[] ary = newHtml.split("#~#");
```

This will do the job, yet there may be other clean ways to replace the br tag.

Answer (score 1):

1) First, it's never a good idea to parse HTMl with a regex. [You can read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

2)You can just take all text between tags.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, charsetName);
String text= doc.text();
System.out.println(text);
```